# Statistical test for change in two continuous variables across two conditions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, descriptive-statistics

I am working on data from a biomechanics study of swimming.

There were two conditions in the study: swimming with normal and fast self-selected speeds (conditions 1 and 2 respectively). There are two measurement variables: cycle times and stroke length. So for each subject, there are 20 cycle times and stroke lengths for each condition in the dataset.

I want to find out the mechanism the subjects used to increase their swimming speed. That is, when going from normal swimming speed to fast swimming speed (condition 1 to 2), which of either cycle time or stroke length changed significantly (and if both are significant, which one increased the most)?

After reading multiple sources (including [here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/spss/whatstat/what-statistical-analysis-should-i-usestatistical-analyses-using-spss/)), I have not found a test that can help me with the above analysis. Any suggestions?

Note: The data is collected for 12 swimmers. We have measured cycle time and stroke length for each swimmer per cycle. For example, each time a subject completes a lap, we get about 15 data points (cycle time, stroke length).

Comment: You need to give more details: How many swimmers? Are their cycle time/stroke length constant or measured continuously? ...

Comment: What would you say is the dependent variable you are trying to study? Time until lap completion?

Comment: That could be considered the dependent variable but its actual value is not relevant. I'm more concerned about finding which predictor (between stroke length and cycle time) is more affected when going from normal swimming condition to fast swimming condition.

Comment: Is the following procedure valid? First I can normalize the data for all subjects and perform independent t test to see which of the two variables changes significantly between condition 1 (normal swimming) and 2 (fast swimming). Then, if both are significant, use Cohen's D to compare their effect size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing up the different dependent variables you can have in your analysis.

One thing is is to see how the different swimming conditions affect cycle time or stroke length. This implies 2 different models in my mind:

$$
C = \alpha_1 + \beta_1 I_{condition=2}
$$

$$
S = \alpha_2 + \beta_2 I_{condition=2}
$$

Where $C$ is cycle speed and $S$ is stroke length and $I$ an indicator function.
However, to the question you seem to be asking, these models will not be very useful in answering. How can you judge $\beta_1 > \beta_2$, since they are in different units?

What you seem to be implying is that $Y = f(S, C)$ where $Y$ is time until lap completion, which means that different cycle time and stroke lengths will lead to different different lap times.

Since you have multiple subjects (swimmers) and multiple laps I suggest you the following approach. This is simplified, since there should be a few more caveats to make it suitable for the hypothesis your are studying.

Let $Y_{i,t}$ be the time until completion of the $i$th swimmer to finish lap $t$. $C_{i,t}$, Let $S_{i,t}$ be the cycle speed and stroke lengths, respectively,  during that swimmer's lap. Also, let $I_{i,t}$ indicate the condition that swimmer $i$ was fast (condition 2) during lap $t$.

$$
Y_{i,t} = \alpha + \beta_1C_{i,t}+\beta_2S_{i,t} + \beta_3I_{i,t}C_{i,t}+\beta_4I_{i,t}S_{i,t}
$$

With this model, you can see that the effect of a higher cycle speed on speed for some one in condition 1 is $\beta_1$, and for a swimmer in condition 2 is $\beta_1+\beta_3$. Additionally, with this model you can test if $\beta_3 > \beta_4$ which is equivalent of asking "is the effect on time until completion of a lap of a higher cycle speed greater the that of stroke length for individuals who are in condition 2?".

Now for some caveats. 1) the variable $Y$, time until lap completion is strictly positive, so a generalised linear model with a gamma link should be more appropriate than a linear model. 2) the average swimmer's time until lap completion can be different due to other reasons other then the modelled condition/stroke lenght/cycle speed. And you should attempt to control for that. Some things come to mind, a) there can be some swimmers who are faster then others, b) the average time to completion should be different across laps. Conditioning on the last lap seems different than the first. This suggests that $t$ should be covariate in the model.

To address all this problems and to test the hypothesis you are after, I would go after hierarchical models (aka multilevel models, repeated measures models, or longitudinal analysis models).